# Hard Drive not allowing me to use max capacity

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have a 1TB SSD that I formatted. It use to allow me to use 960GB. I went to Disk Management and checked the partitions. I have 1 partition for 894GB. I've wiped it and created it again and I can't get my 60+ GBs back. In Disk Part CMD tool it only shows the single 894GB partition. Says the max capacity is 894GB. There is no sign that it's a 960GB except the title of the drive and that I know it was 960 before.

Comment: So before wiping, it used to show 960GB in the same "Disk Part CMD" tool?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. The raw capacity of a (perfect) 1 terabyte disk is roughly 931 GiB, less with the overhead of partitioning and the presence of a filesystem which is roughly 4% in your situation.

[image]

[image]